# Some anomalies with table div. How to remove border?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was working with the div table and came across several anomalies. 1. the Text in cells 1 and 4 is overlaid with the text in cells 2 and 5.(solved by word-break: break-all) 2. the line with text 7 has a black border on the left. 3. The line with text 7 has a width greater than the others. How to make sure that the cells do not overlap and do not go under each other, there is no black border to the left of the text and the div rows are the same width?

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
 border-style: none;
}

.divTableCell {
 border: 0px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;

}


div.blueTable {
  border: 0px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;

  text-align: left;

  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell, .divTable.blueTable  {
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {

 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 
}


.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
```

```html
<div class="divTable blueTable" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:10%">1 Text TextText TextText TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:40%">2 Text Text Text TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:50%">3 Text TextText TextText Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">4Text TextText TextText TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">5Text TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">6Text TextText TextText Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow"><div>7 texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextte xttexttexttexttexttexttextt exttexttexttexttextt xttexttexttexttexttexttex ttexttext</div></div>
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `word-break: break-all;` on your cell and you are missing TableCell on your div (7)

Comment: Why are you not just using a table, if this is tabular data, or grid?

Comment: Ok, thank You, I used a  word-break: break-all; in .divTableCell and it help me to fix problem 1.

Comment: I'm going to use slideToggle() for a div with text 7, and I never yet used grid.

Answer (score 0):

1. the Text in cells 1 and 4 is overlaid with the text in cells 2 and 5.(solved by word-break: break-all) 
   == as you solved it.
2. the line with text 7 has a black border on the left. 
   == this is due to inline css `style="border: 1px solid #000;"` you gave to div with class `class="divTable blueTable"`.
3. The line with text 7 has a width greater than the others
   == here in this row you need to add something like colspan but you can't use colspan here for that i used `display: table-caption` instead of `display: table-row`

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
 border-style: none;
}

.divTableCell {
 border: 0px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;

}


div.blueTable {
  border: 0px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;

  text-align: left;

  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell, .divTable.blueTable  {
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {

 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 
}


.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}

.divCaptionRow {
  display: table-caption;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable blueTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:10%">1 Text TextText TextText TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:40%">2 Text Text Text TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:50%">3 Text TextText TextText Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">4Text TextText TextText TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">5Text TextText Text</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">6Text TextText TextText Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="divCaptionRow"><div>7 texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextte xttexttexttexttexttexttextt exttexttexttexttextt xttexttexttexttexttexttex ttexttext</div></div>
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!. You are very attentive, but problem with size row until there are no solved .